# Ant version compatible with LR 6.2-ce-ga4 java 1.7

Tags: java, ant, liferay

I need to install liferay-portal-tomcat-6.2-ce-ga4 and Java 1.7 u 79 in my testing PC

Could any one help me to get correct ant version and eclipse version for those requirements. 
My Pc Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the latest Apache ant zip from http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi.

and the latest version for Liferay eclipse ide from https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20IDE/2.2.4%20GA5/liferay-ide-eclipse-windows-x64-2.2.4-ga5-201507230603.zip/download.

Thanks & Regards.